# building static library that depends on another static library

Tags: c, static-libraries, static-linking, unix-ar

I have a case where there are two libraries lib1 and lib2. lib2 has dependencies on lib1. In my case lib2 is basically a high level wrapper around the functions inside lib1.
The final application is just going to use functions from lib2 by including the relevant header.
How do I statically build the libraries and link them to the final program?

Answer (score 22):

Static libraries are just archives of object (`.o`) files, so you can't have embedded dependency information. Something like `ar cr lib1.a foo.o bar.o [more object files]` will build your libraries.

Because there is no dependency information, your main program has to link **both** the libraries and it's important to link `lib1` **after** `lib2` when `lib2` depends on `lib1` (otherwise the linker won't find the symbols that are unresolved in `lib2`). A linking step could therefore look like this (assuming you use `gcc` and your libraries are in the current directory):

```
gcc -otest main.o -L. -Wl,-Bstatic -l2 -l1
```

Comment: +1
I thought the same but due to less experience in C I didn't answered.
(Y)

Comment: @rici the linker is not in the scope of the standard. This is about the GNU linker. You can list the same library *twice* in an invocation if necessary.

Comment: For libraries, it is possible to place them twice on the command line:`-l1 -l2 -l1` will handle references in either direction including mutual recursion.

Comment: That's what I just wrote, responding to your now-deleted comment.

Comment: Felix, libraries are not in scope but the linker is part of the implementation. The standard provides for translation units and a mechanism to run a complete program, so there must be something like a linker.

Comment: As to the other, i misread your answer so i deleted the complaint. Typing on glass is slow, at least for me. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make `l2.lib` contain the `l1.lib` objects as well? So when linking to the parent project of `l2.lib` only `l2.lib` will be linked?